# How to force MySQL database to ignore optimizations?

Tags: mysql

This is my database model:

[image]

In my database, table document has 1000 rows, table document_has_term has 700 000 rows and table term has 1070 rows.

This is simple query that join all tables together and select all ids from document:

```
select 
    document.iddocument 
from 
    document 
join 
    document_has_term on document.iddocument = document_has_term.document_iddocument 
join 
    term on term.idterm = document_has_term.term_idterm
```

It takes around **350ms** to execute this query. If I understand it right, it iterates through all 700 000 indexes.

Now before I execute next query I reset cache and make sure **there is no index on `term.term` column**.

Then I execute this query which is same as above only added where statement. Term used for search was randomly chosen from database.

```
select document.iddocument from document join document_has_term on 
document.iddocument=document_has_term.document_iddocument 
join term on term.idterm=document_has_term.term_idterm where term.term=apple
```

Now for some reason, executing this query takes only **3ms**, which is about 100 times faster then previous query and I don't know why. As I understand when there is no index set on `retm.term` it has to iterate over all 700 000 to give me result which would take at least same number of times as it did before.

So I wonder how can I force it to search linear through all database index. I cleared and reset cache and dropped every index from term.term, even reset database many times, nothing helped.

This is example of code where I test query execution time:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myDB";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "FLUSH QUERY CACHE";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$sql = "RESET QUERY CACHE";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$randomTerms = array();
$totalTime=0;

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){
    global $conn, $randomTerms;
    $sql = "select term.term from term order by rand() limit 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $randomTerms[] = $row["term"];
    echo $row["term"]."<br>";
}

foreach ($randomTerms as $t){
    global $totalTime;
    $sql = "select document.iddocument from document join document_has_term on document.iddocument=document_has_term.document_iddocument "
            . "join term on term.idterm=document_has_term.term_idterm where term.term=\"$t\" ";
    $algTime = microtime(true);
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $algTime = microtime(true) - $algTime;
    $totalTime+=$algTime;
}

$averageTime = $totalTime/100;
```

Comment: Put SQL_NO_CACHE in your SELECT statements when testing queries. e.g. `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE term.term from term order by rand() limit 1` . Repeat your tests and update your question with the results you get, please.

Comment: Can you share a `DESC` on the query? We can potentially force an index.

Comment: SQL_NO_CACHE actually helped, thank you very much

Comment: why do you compare `SELECT  ...;` with `SELECT ... WHERE term.term=apple;` these queries are not equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
```

Adding this to the query solved my problem.

Comment: How much time need the queries to run with `SQL_NO_CACHE`?

Comment: Around 230 ms which is less than iterating through 700k rows but it is nice measurable value I can work with. Whn I apply index, then i takes around 12ms.